# Is there an Excel function or a script to find and replace fields that match in two different sheets by another data contained in the second sheet?

Tags: python, automation, openoffice-calc

Today is my 1st time using with Open Office and I need some help to get started.
My boss gave me two Excel files containing data I have to complete.

- The 1st sheet contains in 'A' a supplier code and a bunch a other columns with datas like the product dimensions that I need to keep.
- The 2nd contains in 'A' the same supplier code, tho not in the same order as there is also a lot of them in double, and it has in 'B' a store code.

I need to add a column to the 1st sheet containing the store code if there is a match in both sheet with the code contained in 'A'.

It's not really my job but since everyone is gone for the summer he charged me to do it.

My problem is that both sheets are over 12 000 lines longs, and I know that there is only 700 to 800 articles that will have a match. And since its my 1st time using Excel/OpenOffice (I know I know...) I was wondering if there was a way to automate this work, either with OpenOffice or if I could use a script to do it. I've found a lot similar post but none of them is quite what I need.

Any help is welcome. 
Thx !

Comment: how big are the two files? also how much ram do you have? 12,000 entries might be manageable without too many memory considerations...

Comment: The first one is 7.8mo and the second one only 178kb, I shouldnt have problem with the ram they lend me a macbook to do the job it has 8gb of ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try to let it run disregarding memory concerns and only fix that problem if you encounter it. 12,000 seems like a lot, but you might be surprised at what you can throw at python and have it "just work". I almost exclusively use csv files in programming when I encounter excel or the like...

```
import csv

#    B.csv:
#    store#  part#
#      xx     xx
#      xx     xx
#      xx     xx
#    ...

partNums = {}
with open('B.csv') as bfile:
    breader = csv.DictReader(bfile)
    for row in breader:
        partNums[row['part#']] = row['store#']

#    A.csv
#    part#  tag1  tag2  tag3 ...
#    xx     xx    xx    xx   ...
#    xx     xx    xx    xx   ...
#    xx     xx    xx    xx   ...
#    ...


with open('outfile.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    with open('A.csv', 'rb') as afile:
        areader = csv.reader(afile)
        outwriter = csv.writer(outfile)
        headers = areader.next()
        headers.append('StoreCode')
        outwriter.writerow(headers)
        for row in areader:
            if row[0] in partNums:  #assuming first row is part#
                row.append(partNums[row[0]])
            else:  #value if no store number exists
                row.append('')
            outwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: you'll have to tailor it a bit to fit your file's exact format likely, but basically yah

Comment: Thanks! So I should run this with the 2 files in argument? I'd ask our IT guys but there're busy setting up our new ERP and need this for some of the modules.

Comment: Re, so I've try running it after replacing the format file but I dont know why when I run it its printing me the usage for ImageMagick and then this import: delegate library support not built-in `' (X11) @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1297.
I continue to try with different format and changing my files, meanwhile any idea why it does this ?

Comment: are you trying to run this in open office? this needs to be run from a command line. save it as a .py file and call it from a command prompt

Comment: Yes thats what I did but apparently there is a conflict 'Import' conflict with the import command of imageMagick, I also get a warning saying that partNums doest exist. Is there a lib or something that may be missing ?

Comment: tbh, I don't know what imageMagick is, and I don't think it should be involved at all. If you can export these files as .csv files, the only library you need is the csv library which is part of the standard distribution

Comment: this solution should only be dependent on having a working python 2.7 or 3.4 distribution

Comment: I did just notice a few typos in my code however... capitalization with my variable: `partNums`

Comment: Ok I found the problem, so ImageMagick is a photoshop like prog running in cmd line, and it had a 'Import' in its bash that conflicted with the one in the script but they change the cmd in the newsest version. I upgraded is and in currently downloading python 2.7, it should I'll let you know. (I'm in Africa and my connection doesnt go abose 0,20mo/sec so even python is long to dl...)

Comment: I finally made it work aswell, its more interresing to use than an simple excel function, Im impressed by how fast it runs the 12k line. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You might also try a VLOOKUP() formula.  It might work in Calc with the .xls files, but I would save them both as .ods first just to be safe.  You would write the formula at the top of an empty column in File1, something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;'file:///C:/FolderName/File2.ods'#$Sheet1.$A$1:$B$12000;2;0)
```

The syntax for VLOOKUP with examples is explained in this tutorial: [VLOOKUP questions and answers](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=46746).

Make sure to include the `$` symbols in front of the column letter and row numbers - this tells the spreadsheet to NOT adjust those letters and numbers when you copy/paste the formula.  The first argument (A1 here) that is just plain WILL be adjusted to A2, A3, etc. when copy/pasted so the formula will be matching the appropriate store code on each row.

Once you have that first cell working, copy that cell with the VLOOKUP formula.  Then click on the name box (it's to the left of the formula bar) and type in the range you want to paste that formula into, something like `H2:H12000` and press enter.  The range you typed should be highlighted.  Now paste your formula.

All the matching codes should appear and the non-matching ones will show `#N/A`.  If you want blanks instead of `#N/A` you could do something like

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;'file:///C:/FolderName/File2.ods'#$Sheet1.$A$1:$B$12000;2;0);"";VLOOKUP(A1;'file:///C:/FolderName/File2.ods'#$Sheet1.$A$1:$B$12000;2;0))
```

Basically that says "if this formula returns an error; then show a blank; otherwise show the result of this formula"